# Unable to reach MikTeX items from Start Menu

Tags: miktex, windows

I would like to have MikTeX (the tex compiler) know of a *.sty file for purpose of displaying Stata output. (Basically, I would need to have MikTeX source the a "texmf" directory in which there is a Stata.sty file.) There used to be a dialog window accessible from StartMenu that I could use to specify such "texmf" directory.

However, I cannot reach the dialog window from the StartMenu now. I am also unable to identify the *.exe file found in the root folder of MikTeX.

It would be helpful if anyone could: either identify the *.exe file that could be used to call the dialog window for specifying the user-defined "texmf" directory; or, provide solution for solving the missing "StartMenu" item issue.

(For my case, typing "MikTex" at the start menu does not invoke any query result.)

System: Windows 7, Ultimate

Comment: Your question is not very clear for me.  I have MiKTeX 2.9 running under Windows 7. Clicking on Windows-start I see MiKTeX 2.9 as installed program. If you can not see this link you have a problem with your system installation.  Can you start pdflatex from the terminal? If not, reinstall the complete MiKTeX. BTW: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: To register a local texmf directory, you should use `MiKTeX Options`, more precisely in administrator mode if you want anyone using your computer has access to this directory (`mo_admin.exe`), or in user mode if you want to be alone to use it (`mo.exe`). The usual locations are `C\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64` if you have the 64 bit version, `C\Program Files(x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin` if you have the 32 bit version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon quick search, the dialog window could be accessed through the executable file to be found as the following directory:

If the machine was 64-bit based, it it likely to be found as:

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\mo_admin.exe
```

Otherwise, the "MikTex Options" dialog window will be found as:

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\mo_admin.exe
```

With the help of the IT people at University of Michigan Law School, the Start Menu shortcuts could be recovered through copying those valid shortcuts as a folder to the problematic machine. Dragging the folder to the StartMenu would be all that is needed to fix the StartMenu Item problem.

Comment: Maybe you clicked the option, not create the icons in the Start Menu.

Comment: You should also make shortcuts for the user version of the tools (mo.exe, mpm.exe).

Comment: Agreed. The directory info simply servers as a reference, in case if someone else failed to find the executable file like me.